# PHP if multiple conditions fails

Tags: php, if-statement

what part of my code is incorrect. It keeps rejecting the statment and won't run the code

```
if(!is_numeric($InvAMT) OR $ItemNM='0' OR $InvAMT='A0' OR $SuppUN=='')
   {
     // Run the Code
   }
 else
    {
     exit;
    }
```

PS: I tried replacing the ORs with || also putting each condition into separate parentheses, neither worked.

Comment: $ItemNM = '0' != $ItemNM == 0....

Answer (score 5):

You need two equals signs in the comparison, otherwise you're doing an assignment:

```
$ItemNM == '0'
```

So the full expression would be:

```
if( !is_numeric($InvAMT) OR $ItemNM == '0' OR $InvAMT == 'A0' OR $SuppUN == '')
```

Comment: Yeah, I saw it right after posting it. sorry for that

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
if(!is_numeric($InvAMT) OR $ItemNM=='0' OR $InvAMT=='A0' OR $SuppUN=='')
```

You got the comparison right in the final check, but used the assignment operator for the first two.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I forgot to add the second '=' in my statement

```
if(!is_numeric($InvAMT) or $ItemNM=='' or $InvAMT=='A0' or $SuppUN=='')
```